# Get all rows that are the same and put into own dataframe

Tags: pandas

Say I have a dataframe where there are different values in a column, e.g.,

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'nationality': ['USA', 'USA', 'France', 'UK', 'UK'],
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'nationality', 'age'])
df
```

How do I create a new dataframe(s), where each dataframe contains only the values for USA, only the values for UK, and only the values for France? But here is the thing, say `I don't what to specify a condition like

**Don't want this**

```
# Create variable with TRUE if nationality is USA
american = df['nationality'] == "USA"
```

**I want all the data aggregated for each nationality whatever the nationality is, without having to specify the nationality condition. I just want all the same nationalities together in their own dataframe.** Also, I want all the columns that pertain to that row.

So for example, the function

```
SplitDFIntoSeveralDFWhereColumnValueAllTheSame(column):
   code
```

Will return an array of dataframes with all the values of a column in each dataframe are equal.

So if I had more data and more nationalities, the aggregation into new dataframes will work without changing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a dictionary of dataframes where the keys are the unique values of the `'nationality'` column and the values are the dataframes you are looking for.

```
{name: group for name, group in df.groupby('nationality')}
```

---

***demo***

```
dodf = {name: group for name, group in df.groupby('nationality')}

for k in dodf:
    print(k, '\n'*2, dodf[k], '\n'*2)

France 

   first_name nationality  age
2        NaN      France   36 


USA 

   first_name nationality  age
0      Jason         USA   42
1      Molly         USA   52 


UK 

   first_name nationality  age
3        NaN          UK   24
4        NaN          UK   70
```

Comment: That works thanks. Looks like it returns a Dictionary of Dataframes. One more request. Notice that the nationalities get returned in some unsorted manner. How would I guarantee that the frames were returned in sorted order, France, UK, USA. Need it to work with dates too.

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  I'd advise being more specific and post another question... we like having more questions to answer.

Comment: Actually it is easy. Just use sort_values. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan there you go :-)  glad I could help